# Changing Social Media

Tags: social-sharing

Can anyone tell me how to change my social media links? I've tried everything on google. My wordpress was set up by a third party who is no longer able to help me. I have pretty much covered being able to keep it updated. On my website the links to the social media are at the bottom but not a menus, not a footer, or in the media link. I cannot find a plug-in used to put them there.

Answer (score 1):

Check your widgets or theme options.  If they are not in there they may be in your theme files, check for a file called footer.php.

If you dont have access to the files via FTP you can view theme by going to Admin > Appearance > Editor.

Answer (score 1):

If they are not in any plugin, neither in Jetpack, then probably they put the social links in the theme's files or in a child theme, look at files named like this:

- content.php
- content-single.php
- functions.php
- single.php